# UIViewController load and release strategy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I’m building a game with SpriteKit and Swift based on the logic of navigation described below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425665628-navlogic.png))</sub>

The code below illustrate the logic put in place to go from one screen to another (here to go from the Startup Screen to either the Preferences Setting Screen or the Level Choice Screen)

```
class StartupScreen: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let StartView = self.view as SKView
        let StartScene = StartSceneClass(size: self.view.bounds.size)
        StartView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        StartScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        
        StartView.presentScene(StartScene)
    }

+ some other code

}

class StartSceneClass: SKScene
{

+ some init and game logic code…

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches
        {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            
            switch self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            {
            case self.playButton:                
                let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChoixLevelVC") as ChoixLevelVC
                self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            case self.BoutonPrefs:
                let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayLevelVC") as PlayLevelVC
                self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the same logic as above to go from the Level Choice Screen to the Play Level Screen.

The problems I have are :

- When I go from the Level Choice Screen to the Play Level Screen, I
  see the Startup Screen below during the transition
- When I quit the Play Level Screen, I go back directly to the Startup
  Screen and not to the Level Choice Screen where I came from
- The second time I go from the Level Choice Screen to the Play Level
  Screen, I find back all the sprites of the previous time. The SKScene
  of the Play Level Screen is not deleted when I dismiss the
  UIViewController.

Regarding the last problem, what I want is to completely kill/erase the Play Level Screen each time I quit it.

So far I have implemented `self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)` in either the SKScene or the UIViewController of the called UIViewController to dismiss the view controller.

I have read a lot of stuff regarding the way to dismiss a UIViewController and I have understood that the recommended way is to do it from the calling ViewController (In my case it means that I should dismiss the Play Level Screen from the Level Choice Screen). However, I couldn’t find a Swift example of this way of doing it (lot of Obj-C examples that I can’t understand).

I want to use the less possible the storyboard and to do most of the tasks programmatically. Today I just use the storyboard to create each ViewController  and load it because I couldn’t find a way to code everything yet.

Thanks for any link or advice on the best way to properly implement this kind of navigation logic.

Answer (score 0):

**When I go from the Level Choice Screen to the Play Level Screen, I see the Startup Screen below during the transition**

This sounds to me like the UIViewController you are pushing to has a clear background, in that case, you are still being able to see the underlaying VC.

**When I quit the Play Level Screen, I go back directly to the Startup Screen and not to the Level Choice Screen where I came from**

Are you using popViewController or popToRootViewController? When using popViewController it should work as expected.

**The second time I go from the Level Choice Screen to the Play Level Screen, I find back all the sprites of the previous time. The SKScene of the Play Level Screen is not deleted when I dismiss the UIViewController.**

Correct me if i'm wrong, but in my understanding when you pop a UIViewController, it stays on the heap / in memory for a while until another UIViewController is pushed on to the UINavigationController.

You could try to empty your sprites in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: I'm not using pop/push methods which are related to navigation controller to my understanding and which does not seem to be right choice here.